# Blend the transparent colour backgrounds of two elements stacked on eachother

Tags: css, colors

I'm wondering if there is a way to blend two transparent colours laid over eachother, to achieve a predetermined colour.

I have a menu bar. The background colour of the bar is `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75)`. The logo on the top-left has a solid red background of `#9B0506`. You can check it out live at http://www.phoenixwebdev.com.au/about-our-services/ecommerce/. The site is a work in progress.

[image]

I want to make this red partially transparent, but achieve the exact same red, visually, when there is white behind the menu bar. The transparent black is behind the red and will affect the colour.

Is there a way to calculate the hex value of the red to achieve this? I don't even know how to achieve this with a single transparent item against a solid background let alone with the black complicating things. I can't eyeball it, as I'm colourblind. Even if I could a mathematical solution would nag at me.

So for my situation I'm looking for a method to solve `mystery transparent red colour` stacked on `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75)` stacked on `white` = `#9B0506`

I had a read about css blending at https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/. However this doesn't do what I'm talking about.

Comment: Will this help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743482/calculating-opacity-value-mathematically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on experimentation, I managed to get the exact color using `rgba(163,0,2,.92)`. The below demo renders a box filled with the colours stacked on each other, giving `#9B0506` as the overall color.

Also, you don't need to rely on your eyesight to test theoretical values, free applications such as [ColorPic](http://www.iconico.com/colorpic/) and many others allow you to inspect pixels on your screen real time, and get their HEX/RGB color values directly.

I understand that this does not provide any means of calculating it programmatically, but it could serve as a reference point if someone's trying to test an algorithm for this.

```css
.a { z-index: 1; background: white }
.b { z-index: 2; background: rgba(0,0,0,.75) }
.c { z-index: 3; background: rgba(163,0,2,.92) }

.a, .b, .c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
```

---

As per your request, I've tried reproducing the color with a lower opacity value. I've found that `rgba(171,0,0,.85)` is very close to the target color and it has slightly more opacity as well. At this point I'm fairly certain the exact color can't be achieved at any other value than that mentioned before, but this should be a close enough approximation that there won't be much of a difference. The demo below has the old color and the new one next to each other, with the color code they produce written on each half.

```css
.a { z-index: 1; background: white }
.b { z-index: 2; background: rgba(0,0,0,.75) }
.c { z-index: 3; background: rgba(163,0,2,.92) }
.d { z-index: 3; background: rgba(171,0,0,.85) }

.a, .b, .c, .d {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.a, .b {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.c, .d {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  font-family: "Consolas", monospace;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}
.c { left: 0 }
.d { right: 0 }
```

```html
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="c"><span>#9B0506</span></div>
<div class="d"><span>#9B0A0A</span></div>
```

Comment: This certainly gives me the identical colour. Thanks very much! Best answer so far. Unfortunately the transparency effect is barely visible, do you think it's possible to achieve this with a darker red and more transparency? That said, I do understand we're working with dark colours here.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, it's easier to work with colors in rgba than in hexa.

So, your requested result is 9b0506 -> rgb(155, 5, 6)

Next, the formula for any channel is

(f * a) + (b * (1-a))

where f is the foreground value, b the background value for the channel

Applying this formula for the first 2 layers, white and the black with opacity of  0.75, gives

0 * 0.75 + (255 * 0.25) = 63

Thus the base is rgb (63, 63, 63)

Now, the upper layer can have any alpha that you want ... But for the green channel, the expected result is 5, and the contribution of the base layer alone will be 63 * ( 1 - a). Thus, a value of (1 -a ) greater than 0.08 will contribute to the green chanel more than 5, exceding the total result.

Since the values can not be negative, the **minimum** alpha for the result is (1 - 0.08) = 0.92.

Now, we can calculate the r g b values:

r = (155 - (63 * 0.08)) / 0.92 =  163

b = (6 - (63 * 0.08)) / 0.92 =  1

(the green channel, as dicussed before, is 0)

So the result is rgba (163, 0, 1, 0.92).

If you want higher transparencies, you need to lower the green channel restrictions (or the green channel result goes higher, or the base color goes lower.. this would be achieved making the black layer have higher opacity)

Comment: Where did you learn this lol? Amazing answer :D Way better then just trying every single rgba value in js till it finds a match lol

Comment: Damn that's great work. @seahorsepip after reading this answer I googled the formula and found this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing.

Comment: @JamesJones Thanks for the link, I've used compositing before in photoshop but never knew it could be used like this and never actually read into it. So I'll give it a read :D

Comment: The result should be `rgba (163, 0, 1, 0.92)` not `0.08` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @DJDavid98 Yes, you are right... And the "maximum" should be "minimum" ... Wel spotten !

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with gradient for background

```
background: linear-gradient(direction, color-stop1, color- stop2, ...);
```

Comment: That is not what I'm looking for. You're talking about blending two colours across a gradient right? I'm talking about mixing the colours of two elements stacked on top of eachother.

Comment: sorry , I misunderstood

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to calculate it. Though we can bruteforce it :D

Consider a canvas element A and canvas element B.
User can input color A(#9B0506) and color B(rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.75)) then a js loop will try every single color(rgba) on top of color B til and output the closest match to color A.

I'll try to make a program in jsfiddle.

Comment: The loop would have to be iterated through manually right? I'm not opposed to your idea, just clarifying.

Comment: The loop will be done with js, currently working on a program to do the job. Keep in mind it will hang the browser for a while till it's done (progress can be seen in the browser console).

Comment: I'm scared you're misinterpreting the question slightly. I've edited to try and make it clearer